# What happens when a pass-by-reference parameter gets stored in the callee object, and then deleted by the caller?

Tags: c++, reference, scope, pass-by-reference, observer-pattern

Coming from C, I'm new to C++'s concept of 'reference' object. To help myself figure it out, I've got a slightly-modified implementation of the Observer pattern.

Class A:

```
class A
{
   public:
      A (int x) : m_x (x) {}

   private:
      int m_x;
}
```

Class B:

```
class B
{
   public:
      void Register (A& listener) { m_currentListener = listener; }

   private:
      A& m_currentListener;
}
```

Class C:

```
class C
{
   public:
      void RegisterNewDefaultListener ()
      {
         A tempA (42);
         m_observer.Register (tempA);
         m_lastRegisteredListener= tempA;
      }

   private:
      B m_observer;
      A& m_lastRegisteredListener;
}
```

It's the `C#RegisterNewDefaultListener` method that I'm worried about: it creates a local instance of `A`, then passes it by reference to two different places and stores it away.

But then that local instance goes immediately out of scope, and would get destructed. What happens to those aliases holding on to that reference? Do they get invalidated? Or does that local `A` not go away until all references to it go away, too?

Comment: Yes, those references will be invalid when the object is destroyed and any attempt to access a member variable or invoke a non-static member function on that object reference will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: An aside: in C++, we write `C::RegisterNewDefaultListener` (not `#`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say what you're asking about.  For starters, class `B`
needs a constructor in order to compile, precisely because it contains
a reference: that reference *must* be initialized in the constructor,
and can never be changed afterwards.  The same thing applies to `C`.

Of course, you could achieve the same effect by using pointers, and then
you could change them after the constructor has run.  And registering
the address of a local variable with something which will outlive the
local variable is generally a bad idea; if it's listeners you're
interested in, the listener itself will generally do the registration,
keep track of where it has registered, and will deregister itself in its
destructor.  (It will generally also delete itself when it receives the
relevant event.)  But you don't say what your actual problem is.

More generally, dangling references and pointers are a problem in just
about all languages; for one reason or another, the listener becomes
irrelevant or inactive, and it must deregister itself.  C++ is no
different than any other language in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, the references behave in a very similar way to C pointers - they will be referring to non-existing instances and bad things will follow. Generally, references are not to be stored (with some notable exceptions) - they are mainly intended to be used to pass parameters around without copying them, with the caller providing the guarantee of their validity until the called method finishes.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as with pointers, and attempting to access the object if it no longer exists results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `A& m_currentListener;` in `class B`, it means that you have to initialize it to something in the constructor (that is, bind the reference to an object), otherwize the code won't compile. So let's assume that you have (rather ugly, but it's not important here):

```
B::B() : m_currentListener(*new A(0)) {}
```

Then in `B::Register()` the object which `m_currentListener` references is assigned to a copy of `listener` passed to that function. You are not rebinding `m_currentListener` to reference a different object! So there's no undefined behavior here, but the code works probably not how you want it to.